# Exception in thread "main" when calling methods from switch in menu class

Tags: java

My problem is: 
When I'm trying to call method newFile.createYear(); from switch in menu terminal prints error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.register.file.CreateFile.showYears(CreateFile.java:140)
at com.register.file.CreateFile.createYear(CreateFile.java:30)
at com.register.main.Menu.registers(Menu.java:30)
at com.register.main.Menu.menu(Menu.java:132)
at com.register.main.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

Problem does not occur when I'm running program inside eclipse. I'm running program by typing `java com.register.main.Main` in terminal.

Additionally when I'm trying to go back to last menu, after calling a method, (even in Eclipse):

The part of code from switch:

```
    switch (selection) {
            case 1:
//method that clearing terminal (I can't find anything better :( )
                newClear.clearConsole();
//method that work only in eclipse, not terminal
                newFile.createYear();
//name of current menu (back option) - doesn't work
                registers();

                break;

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException   at
> java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)    at
> java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)    at
> java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)     at
> java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)     at
> com.register.main.Menu.registers(Menu.java:24)    at
> com.register.main.Menu.registers(Menu.java:31)    at
> com.register.main.Menu.menu(Menu.java:134)    at
> com.register.main.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

https://github.com/JakubKacperski/Register

Comment: so, you have one object you call an instance member (method) on before you initialize it, and you call an instance member (method) on a variable that doesn't exist.

Comment: Any ideas how can I fix it? I'm really fresh at Java as You can see ;)

Comment: instantiate the variable, and use the correct variablename when calling something on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a check if the directory "Registers" exists in your class `CreateFile` in method `showYears()`:

```
    File yearsDirs = new File("Registers"); 

    if (!yearsDirs.exists()){ //Create "Registers" when it does not exists.
        yearsDirs.mkdir();
    }

    File[] dirs = yearsDirs.listFiles();

    for (File dir : dirs) {
        if (dir.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.print("Registers ");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Register ");
        }
        try {
            System.out.println(dir.getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error.");
        }
    }
```

Without the check, you get a NullPointerException when calling .listFiles() 'cause the directory "Registers" does not exist.
In Eclipse, you probably have a directory "Registers" under your project Register. When called from the terminal, you've probably not.

---

Per comment of OP: you can write a loop like:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Menu newMenu = new Menu();

        boolean continuePlaying = newMenu.menu();

        while (continuePlaying) {
            continuePlaying = newMenu.menu();
        }
    }

}
```

And change your method `menu()`s return type to `boolean` instead of `void`.

---

Also, you are using multiple `Scanner`s. I suggest using only one. When you close a `Scanner`, it looks like it also closes the other ones. In your method `createYear()` in class `CreateFile` you call `reader.close()` at the end. When I remove that line, the above loop works perfectly. When I let it as it is, I get a `NoSuchElementException` like you got.

Comment: Ok, but why after calling method showYears() I cant' go back to  registers(); ? Is there other way to go back to menu?

Comment: @JakubKacperski After an Exception occurs that is not catched, your program will stop. You can add a null-check if `dirs == null`. I'll update the code.

Comment: @JakubKacperski Instead of a null check, you can check if "Registers" exists. I've updated the code.

Comment: Yeah, but even if create.Year(); works (in eclipse) I can't go back to my menu (registers();), after ending the method create.Year();.

Comment: @JakubKacperski When your program starts, it calls `newMenu.menu();`. In that method, you read the input and put that into a switch statement. After the switch is done, the method ends. You need to put a loop there.

Comment: @JakubKacperski Did it work out for you? If not, what is still not working?